# Can a BlackBerry app built for one model be downloaded from AppWorld with another model of BB

Tags: blackberry

I understand that a BlackBerry app has to be built to support the screen resolution and capabilities of a specific model of BB. However, does that mean that owners of other BB models will be unable to download and use that app from AppWorld? Is there any automatic downscaling that occurs similar to what you see with iPhone apps working natively on iPad?

Usual caveat here: I'm new to BB development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (AFAIK) when you publish your app on the AppWorld you can explicitly define device models ans OS versions to be allowed for the app to run on (thus to be downloaded to). Yes, this means that owners of other BB models will be unable to download and use that app from AppWorld. There is no any automatic downscaling unless you do it from your code.